# Is there a key combination which will allow win7 to boot WITHOUT the programs in the start menu?

Tags: windows-7, boot

Is there a key combination which will allow win7 to boot WITHOUT the programs in the start menu?

Sometimes I want to just access one program and the computer takes too long to boot with everything up.

Edit: I guess I'm not clear enough, sorry. What I am looking for is a key or combination which will allow me, during boot, to stop all programs which I previously have set to automatically load. I can then load, for example, my voip phone for use without waiting for all the programs to load.

Comment: Do you mean without startup tasks? Most things in the Start menu don't do anything at bootup, they're just links you can click on when you want them. Loading those links takes, from a human perspective, no discernible time.

Comment: Thanks you. I have Outlook, my voip phone and skype set to load when I boot. I would like to stop these, especially Outlook which takes minutes. I may want to just load a browser to see an address, for example.

Comment: Hi - to have full control on which programs and services loading during the boot process, download and run autoruns from Microsoft > https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: *"Is there a key combination ..."* -- Create another user account without those startup programs, and then log in as that user.

Comment: That's after boot. I just want to get to a browser asap.

Comment: No, there is not. [They removed it in Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_Vista#User_accounts_and_Winlogon). Please consider rewording your question to be about the problem (easily skipping start-ups), and clarify which start-up types you want to bypass (Startup folder, Registry Run, Startup Tasks, etc.), and what you've already tried.  Otherwise I'd consider it a yes, no question, which is basically off-topic. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 They removed *what*? These aren't threaded comments here. I see nothing in that list that would prevent somebody from, say, implementing the suggestion from sawdust... In fact, I knew there wouldn't be, because I've had multiple user accounts on my machines ever since Vista (though not for the reason asked about here) and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way, but not out of the box. The solution is to create a second boot menu entry that will launch Windows in safe mode with networking, which will bypass most startup routines and let you load Windows quickly - albeit with most system services and virtually all startup software disabled, which does sound like what you want anyway.

The easiest way to do this if you're comfortable with the command line would be to launch an elevated command prompt and carry out the following instructions:

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Windows (Safe Mode with Networking)"
```

Make note of the {GUID} it returns to use below:

```
bcdedit /set {GUID} safeboot networking
```

If you'd rather not use the command line, you can still do this with the free [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). After installing, run it and use it to add a new Windows entry:

[image]

and then go to advanced options and configure it to load as Safe Mode with Networking and save:

[image]

Selecting this entry at boot time will load Windows in this selective startup mode, bypassing startup applications.

Comment: Thank you. It looks beyond my meage capabilities, but I will spend some time and see if I can feel competent to try this.

Comment: I don't suggest you do, one wrong setting and it wont boot and you don't have the skills to fix that.

Comment: @Moab hello again :) Perhaps not for Xavierjazz but certainly a valid answer for other users looking for a similar answer. Though I'd recommend dual-booting with a light Linux distro instead myself :)